# 4 в паттерне .mp3-файла

Tags: javascript, файлы, mp3

Получаю паттерн:

```js
export function getFileTypeHeader(blob, callback) {

  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
    const arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result));

    let header = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      header += arr[i].toString(16);
    }

    callback(header);
  };


  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob.slice(0, 4));
}
```

Кормлю туда `.mp3`. Ожидаю результат `494433`, а получаю `4944334`. Откуда там 4(последняя)?

Comment: А какой результат при `blob.slice(0, 10)`? :) И чем является `blob`?

Comment: `toString(16).padStart(2, "0")`

Comment: @gil9red `blob` - это это файл из `FileList`. Файлы загружаются пользователем через тег `html`. `blob.slice(0, 4)` - потому, что 4 байта достаточно для определения формата файла, нет?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, ага, вы правы, первые 4 байта файла - заголовок: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

Comment: @teran спасибо. Увидел проблему

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, так то понятно почему у вас такой результат. `slice(0, 4)` отрезало 4 байта, далее вы эти байты приводите как строку в HEX, но метод `toString` не делает добивание слева 0 до 2 символов, поэтому число 4 станет просто `"4"`, а не `"04"`, что вам в ответе написали :) `let b = 4;` `console.log(b.toString(16))`

Comment: @gil9red почему 4 не указали здесь https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2 `В столбце ИСО 8859-1 указано, как расшифровывается сигнатура файла стандартной для UNIX-подобных операционных систем утилитой file при языковой кодировке ИСО 8859-1.`, как я понял те 3 байта это результат выполнения той утилиты, а не содержимого файла mp3

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, сделал скрипт, которым считал файлы mp3, вытащил первые 4 байта из файлов, получились такие значения: `b'ID3\x03' = 49443303`, `b'ID3\x04' = 49443304`, `b'\xff\xf3H\xc4' = FFF348C4`, где слева первые 4 байта, а справа их HEX значение. Что совпадает с той таблицей форматов, т.к. там первая последовательность как `FFF3`

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, нагуглил статью с разбором формата mp3, пример заголовка ID3: http://lisper.ru/pcl/practical-an-id3-parser#ID3%20Tag%20Header

Comment: @gil9red Получается, что актуальные до сих пор две версии тега. И для проверки `.mp3` надо писать, либо регулярку либо `case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blob.slice(0, 4)` — вы же отрезаете 4 байта. Видимо, четвёртый байт как раз `0x04`, только `0` не добавляется перед `4`.